# correct path not being displayed while reading a file using s3.glob

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am reading multiple csv files from a folder using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
bucket='<my_s3_bucket_name>'
object = '<my-file-path>/*.csv'
path= s3.glob('s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, object))
path
```

When I display the list of csv files, I get all the csv files in the folder but the path comes without the s3 prefix and when I try to read the csv file, it gives me
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/fsspec/s3fs/issues/509

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `s3fs` do you have?  I somewhere there was a conflict between `s3fs` and `boto`.

I downgraded `s3fs` to version 0.4 some time ago, and your error does not reproduce on my machine.